# How to impelment a foriegn key in sql?

Tags: sql

I tried writing it like that but i keep getting errors but when i removed the line it worked how do i set a foreign key in this?

````
    PlayerNum int,
    PlayerName varchar(255),
    PlayerPosition varchar(255),
    NumOfRedCards int,
    NumOfYellowCards int,
    Goals int,
    Fouls int,
    
    PRIMARY KEY (PlayerNum),
    /*FOREIGN KEY (TeamName) REFERENCES Teams(TeamName)*/
);```
````

Comment: When asking a SQL question, please add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as syntax and functionality between them varies. Adding that tag will help you get an answer more quickly, as well as avoiding wasting the time of people who write an answer for one DBMS only to find out it won't work on the one you're using. Also, you don't need the *database* tag, as the use of the SQL tag means you're using a database already - you can't use SQL without one.

Comment: Also, without seeing the DDL for your Teams database, it's almost impossible to do anything but guess at what the problem is, because the reference is to something we can't see. You might benefit from reading [How to write a good SQL question])https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a column defined for TeamName in your table. Try this:

````
    PlayerNum int,
    PlayerName varchar(255),
    PlayerPosition varchar(255),
    NumOfRedCards int,
    NumOfYellowCards int,
    Goals int,
    Fouls int,
    TeamName varchar(255),

    PRIMARY KEY (PlayerNum),
    FOREIGN KEY (TeamName) REFERENCES Teams(TeamName)
);```
````

That should work, assuming that you have a Teams table with a defined primary key of TeamName.

NOTE: I would highly recommend NOT having a varchar for a primary key. A far better implementation would be:

````
    PlayerNum int,
    PlayerName varchar(255),
    PlayerPosition varchar(255),
    NumOfRedCards int,
    NumOfYellowCards int,
    Goals int,
    Fouls int,
    TeamId int,

    PRIMARY KEY (PlayerNum),
    FOREIGN KEY (TeamId) REFERENCES Teams(TeamId)
);```
````

You can always join tables on the ID to get the team name, or at worst write a view for a flattened structure to query against.

```
SELECT p.PlayerNum, p.PlayerName, ..., t.TeamName FROM Players p
LEFT JOIN Teams t ON p.TeamId = t.TeamId
WHERE p.PlayerId = 1
```

Comment: I forgot to add - the reason an int makes a better primary key (IMHO) is because the key is a lot less likely to change and because of familiarity. However, I've also used tables that had a char(10) primary key, because the 10 characters were codes that would never change and had contextual meaning - changing the code would change the contents of that data. But I think that's a rather niche case.